# Proper method to modify the STS web.config across the farm via C#?

Tags: development

I need to be able to modify, via C# in a SharePoint solution, the STS web.config across multiple servers.  What is the proper way to do this since the WebConfigModificationn class doesn't take this web.config into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer job that is run once on feature activation. Chris Keyser has a post about updating settings on each server in a farm, and you can use that as a base for your code.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chriskeyser/archive/2010/12/20/using-a-sharepoint-timer-job-to-deploy-settings-in-a-farm-for-registering-event-sources.aspx

Comment: I've been thinking over this one, and I'm wondering if it wouldn't be a good idea to create a "STS sync"-type Timer Job.  All changes made by the administrator would be stored in a config file that the STS sync would then execute and update the STS web.config for each server in the farm.  It would periodically run to validate that the STS config was consistent.

Only issue I'm having is how to properly identify the *path* to the STS web.config.  I can hard code it, but that wouldn't be a good idea.